# Two different definitions of "energy space"

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I am wondering whether the following two constructions actually define the same space.

**Construction 1** (taken from Lieb-Loss *Analysis*, 2nd ed., section 8.2). Define $D^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ to be the space of all functions $f\in L^1_{\mathrm{loc}}$ whose distributional gradient $\nabla f$ belongs to $L^2$ and that *vanish at infinity*, meaning that the level sets $\{\lvert f \rvert > a\}$ have finite measure for all $a>0$. Let 
$$\lVert f\rVert_{D^1}^2=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \lvert \nabla f(x)\rvert^2\, dx.$$

**Construction 2** (taken from T.Tao *Nonlinear dispersive equations*, Appendix A). Define $\dot{H}^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ to be the completion of the Schwartz class $\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with respect to the norm 
$$\lVert f \rVert_{\dot{H}^1}^2=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \lvert \nabla f(x)\rvert^2\, dx.$$

I guess that the answer is affirmative. The proof of this guess amounts to showing that the Schwartz class is dense in $D^1(\mathbb{R^n})$. This should use in some essential way the "vanish at infinity" condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall the standard Gagliardo-Nirenberg-Sobolev inequality, valid for $1\leq p<n$,

$$
\| u\|_{L^{p^*}(\mathbb{R}^n)} \leq C\| \nabla u\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)}, \qquad u\in W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n).
$$

Here $p^*=np/(n-p)$ is the Sobolev exponent.

This implies that $\dot{H}^1 (\mathbb{R}^n)=\{ u\in L^{2^*}(\mathbb{R}^n): \nabla u\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)\}$, so it suffices to show that if $u\in D^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ then $u\in L^{2^*}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Take such an $u$ and define

$$
u_n:= \min\{ \max\{ |u|-1/n,0\}, n-1/n\}.
$$

We have that $u_n\in W^{1,1}_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $|\nabla u_n|= |\nabla u|1_{1/n<|u|<n}$, so that clearly $\nabla u_n\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Now to estimate $u_n$ we see that

$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |u_n|^{p} dx = \int_{|u|>1/n} |u_n|^{p}dx \leq (n-1/n)^{p}m(\{ |u|>1/n\}) <\infty.    
$$

We conclude that $u_n\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for all $1<p<\infty$, in particular $u_n\in H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ so that the usual GNS inequality applies and we get

$$
\| u_n\|_{L^{2^*}(\mathbb{R}^n)} \leq C \| \nabla u_n\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)} \leq C\| \nabla u\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)}.
$$

Now just apply Fatou's lemma on the left hand side.

Note: What we prove is that GNS inequality continues to hold for functions in $D^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Comment: I understand you point, you completely address the question. I only have a doubt on a minor detail. If you define $u_n$ like you did, how can you say that $u_n\in W^{1,1}_{\mathrm{loc}}$? Indeed, $u_n$ might have a jump discontinuity at points where $u(x)=\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro: Notice that $u_n=v_n-1/n$ where $v_n=|u|$ if $1/n<|u|<n$, $v_n=1/n$ if $1/n>|u|$ and $v_n=n$ if $|u|>n$. Therefore there can be no jump discontinuities. Another way of looking at this is recalling that the operations of taking absolute value and the maximum/minimum with respect to a constant preserve the Sobolev classes (this is an exercise in Evans' book for example)

Comment: @Jose27 +1 (you mean "preserve *first-order* Sobolev classes", of course).